# Making Global Struct in C++ Program

Tags: c++, struct, global

I am trying to make **global** structure, which will be seen from any part of the source code. I need it for my big Qt project, where some global variables needed. Here it is: 3 files (global.h, dialog.h & main.cpp). For compilation I use Visual Studio (Visual C++).

*global.h*

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_

typedef struct  TNumber {
    int g_nNumber;
} TNum;

TNum Num;

#endif
```

*dialog.h*

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H_
#define DIALOG_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "global.h"

using namespace std;

class   ClassB {
public:
    ClassB() {};

    void    showNumber() {
        Num.g_nNumber = 82;
        cout << "[ClassB][Change Number]: " << Num.g_nNumber << endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

and *main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "global.h"
#include "dialog.h"

using namespace std;

class   ClassA {
public:
    ClassA() {
        cout << "Hello from class A!\n";
    };
    void    showNumber() {
        cout << "[ClassA]: " << Num.g_nNumber << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ClassA  ca;
    ClassB  cb;
    ca.showNumber();
    cb.showNumber();
    ca.showNumber();
    cout << "Exit.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I`m trying to build this little application, compilation works fine, but the linker gives me back an error:

`1>dialog.obj : error LNK2005: "struct TNumber Num" (?Num@@3UTNumber@@A) already defined in main.obj`

Is there exists any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: @mosg: And don't use leading or trailing underscores in your header include guards, and never ever use `using namspace std;` in headers.

Comment: @quamrana: but if i need to `cout` or print some text from the header, its like in example (dialog.h)? I have to use `using namespace std;` command.

Comment: @quamrana: there's nothing wrong with trailing underscores (apart from looking freaky). @mosg: you should either move the code to a source file, or qualify the symbols as `std::cout` and `std::endl`. Putting a `using` declaration in a header file can cause subtle errors in code that includes the header.

Comment: @Mike:  I think you can get into trouble with name clashes when linking to other languages if you use trailing underscores - best avoided.

Comment: You shouldn't use 'typedef struct Foo { } Foo;' in C++.  'struct Foo { };' works just fine.  Trailing underscores are fine, too, and are used by many.  /Leading/ underscores may lead to linking conflicts with other languages, and using leading underscores with capital letters would violate the standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  First, Don't define `num` in the header file.  Declare it as `extern` in the header and then create a file `Global.cpp` to store the global, or put it in `main.cpp` as Thomas Jones-Low's answer suggested.

Second, don't use globals.

Third, `typedef` is unnecessary for this purpose in C++.   You can declare your struct like this:

```
struct  TNum {
    int g_nNumber;
};
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if an alternative for globals were offered

Comment: @WilliamFitzPatrick Globals have their place, especially _static_ globals which are only visible inside the specific source file. Maybe your program simply isn't million lines with hundreds of people working on it? Maybe passing that configuration object from one function to the other all over the code doesn't make sense? Maybe you just stick your configuration into one static global struct so all of your local-to-that-file functions can access the configuration which is only even written by *one* parsing function but read in several places.

Answer (score 3):

In global.h

```
extern TNum Num;
```

then at the top of main.cpp

```
TNum Num;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're writing in C++ use this form of declaration for a struct:

```
struct  TNumber {
    int g_nNumber;
};

extern TNumber Num;
```

The typedef is unnecessary.