# Updating an External Struct Using Method in C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently playing around with the opendnp3 package by automatak. https://github.com/automatak/dnp3/blob/2.0.x/cpp/examples/outstation/main.cpp.

What I can't get my head around is how to update the information in a Struct (defined out of scope of the class) without passing the struct into the class (which I don't think I can do as my code never actually calls the method so I cannot change what is passed to the method when it is called).

Inheritance Diagram:
[image]

I have overwritten the virtual method DoOperate in the SimpleCommandHandler class by creating my own class (MyCommandHandler). Anything back from the DoOperate function is powered by asio.

```
struct State
{
    double value0 = 0;
    double value1 = 0;
    bool binary0 = false;
    bool binary1 = false;

};

State state;

class MyCommandHandler : public SimpleCommandHandler
{
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<ICommandHandler> Create()
    {
        return std::make_shared<MyCommandHandler>();
    }

    MyCommandHandler() : SimpleCommandHandler(CommandStatus::SUCCESS) {}

protected:

    void DoOperate(const ControlRelayOutputBlock& command, uint16_t index, OperateType opType) {

            ////*** This is where I need to update the Struct ***////
            ////    state.value0 = 30;                           ////
            ////    state.value1 = 30;                           ////
            ////    state.binary0 = true;                        ////
            ////    state.binary1 = true;                        ////   
    }

    }
};
```

The only way that I can think of is to make the Struct global but this seems to be poor coding practice from what I have read here [Making Global Struct in C++ Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500677/making-global-struct-in-c-program).

So in short I would like to know - what is the best practice for modifying data (a Struct) external to a class using a method (DoOperate) that is triggered by some external event?

I've been struggling with this one for a while now so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Keep a reference or smart pointer to the object as a class member?

Comment: If there is only one state in the whole program, you could use the singleton pattern, instead of the global variable. But @NathanOliver has imho the best solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver suggested a form of the pimpl idiom, which you might want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with global objects is that you could run into problems with the initialization or destruction order. So in theory `DoOperate` might be called at time when `State state` is not yet initialized or when it is already destructed (which could haven when the on application exit).

But even if this is might not be the case for your application, you still want to make if safe by design.

For your `MyCommandHandler` it should not be important when `DoOperate` is called, so the `MyCommandHandler` object either needs to own the `state` over its whole live time, or you should passed it as argument to  `DoOperate`  if it is only required when `DoOperate` is called.

If you pass it as argument to the `DoOperate` then the object calling that operator should own the state object either for its whole lifetime or should get it as argument to the function that calls `DoOperate`. ...

If you really want to use a global state object then you could so something like that:

```
std::shared_ptr<State> get_global_state() {
   static std::shared_ptr<State> state = std::make_shared<State>();

   return state;
}


class MyCommandHandler : public SimpleCommandHandler
{
public:
    MyCommandHandler() : state_(get_global_state()) {}

    static std::shared_ptr<ICommandHandler> Create()
    {
        return std::make_shared<MyCommandHandler>();
    }

    MyCommandHandler() : SimpleCommandHandler(CommandStatus::SUCCESS) {}

    void DoOperate(const ControlRelayOutputBlock& command, uint16_t index, OperateType opType) {
        // state_-> value0 = ...
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<State> state_;
};
```

Or a code like this if you pass it as argument to `DoOperate`

```
struct HandlerCaller {
  void call_handlers() {
     for( auto &handler : handlers ) {
        handler->DoOperate(state_.get(), /*...*/ )
     }
  }

  std::shared_ptr<State> state_;
}


class MyCommandHandler : public SimpleCommandHandler
{
    void DoOperate(State * const state, const ControlRelayOutputBlock& command, uint16_t index, OperateType opType) {
        // state-> value0 = ...
    }
};
```

I personally don't like singletons, but the important part is the ownership here.